# Custom control and required field validator

Tags: c#, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

i am creating a custom control for the textbox.Let say when the textbox's action is **edit** , the textbox will render same as textbox .On the other hand , when the textbox is action  is **view**, then textbox will render as label.But now i got a problem , how can i validate my textbox with the required field validator when the textbox's action is edit?Here is my coding

```
[ToolboxData(@"<{0}:cusTextBox runat=""server"" Action=""Edit"" />")]

public class cusTextBox:TextBox
{
    public string Action
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["Action"];
            return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Action"] = value;
        }
    }

    public override void RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (Action ==gbcCommandVariable.CommandEdit)
        {
            base.RenderControl(writer);

        }

        else if (Action == gbcCommandVariable.CommandView)
        {

            writer.Write(String.Format(@"<span ID=""{0}"" style=""display:inline-block; white-space:inherit"" >{1}</span> ", this.ClientID, this.Text));
        }
    }

}
```

My front end

```
             <cc1:cusTextBox ID="cusTextBox1" runat="server" Action="View" ></cc1:cusTextBox>
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click1" 
                 Text="Button" />
             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                 ControlToValidate="cusTextBox1" 
    ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Please help me .Urgent.THanks

Comment: Why write a different element out that will cause the validation control to throw an exception, why not simply apply a style that makes the TextBox render with the same appearance?

Comment: can u give me some example?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe

```
   [ValidationProperty("Text")]
   public class cusTextBox:TextBox
```

attribute helps you.